# First time Google Map API

Tags: android, google-maps

I am a first time Android Studio user, trying to get the `Google Map` app to run from the samples provided.  `Android-Studio` is running on a `Gentoo Linux` platform, using `Java 8`.  I have followed the directions on how to add `Google Play services`, added the definition to `Gradle`, far as I can tell it is the virtual device that does not have Google play service support.  I have also added pro-guard rules, error is always the same.  The build rules and dependencies have the entries from the documentation.  It looks like it should work.

It is obvious that I am missing something basic.  The basic HelloWorld works fine, I am stumbling on Google's security and the mechanism by which they are invoked.  Reviewing the documentation, I see references to `GoogleAPIClient` -- Do I have to setup the client connection before trying to connect?  Is there, perhaps sample code where this process is defined correctly, with all its pieces?

The studio itself is at current revision levels.  From the error, is it possible I have missed something else, the `ActivityNotFound` exception?

The LogCat message stream

```
09-10 10:07:16.449    1006-1006/cx.ath.klatt.test1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:840)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 10:07:18.929    1006-1006/cx.ath.klatt.test1 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1006 SIG: 9
09-10 10:07:47.989    1035-1035/cx.ath.klatt.test1 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
```

Comment: Please post your code for this activity. Also as you can see the last line says "Play services missing".

Answer (score 0):

The device in which you are installing, the google play services need to be installed and need to be up to date also.